# Identify this mite from Rajasthan (India)

Tags: species-identification, entomology, arachnology

[image]

Can anyone tell me the classification of this bug? I found it in Rajasthan after it rained.

Comment: What’s the scale on the picture? It looks like some kind of mite, but those are generally < 1mm in size

Comment: red velvet mite of some kind. they get pretty big

Comment: Also, please update your question with approximate size of the organism and the habitat you found it in (for future reference). thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hi it definitely looks like a red velvet mite.  They often are called "rain bugs".  They are of a variety of species and sizes and can be quite large - up to 1 or 2 Cm. These links might help.

https://study.com/academy/lesson/red-velvet-mite-facts-life-cycle-diet.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trombidiidae

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OtHYSIRCZ1c

Answer (score 0):

This is a [Trombidium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trombidium_holosericeum) mite (class Arachnida).

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! When answering identification questions inclusion of an uploaded image for comparison will help you get a more favorable response to your posting. If you can provide details (ideally with references) for what characters led you to this identification that would be even better. ——— You may also wish to take the tour: biology.stackexchange.com/tour and then consult the help pages on the standards for how to effectively provide answers — see: biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer. Thanks! 